# What are differences betwen AlertDialog and AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, builder, difference

Which one is ideal for creating alert dialog? what are differences

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
```

or

```
AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext()).create();
```

Comment: Better to write `AlertDialog.Builder builder` and `AlertDialog alertDialog = ....`. The first one is just a builder (an utility), the second one is the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Basically `AlertDialog` is implemented by **Design Builder Pattern**.

*Design Builder Pattern* provides flexibility of adding dynamic API methods at any class rather that changing any existing code from it. Only disadvantage is it should not directly create object of that class. It should always have Builder class prepared for that.

So, if you try creating object of `AlertDialog` something like **`new AlertDialog()`**, you won't be able to & here's where Builder pattern comes to picture.

Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for more details.